# White lines in object's edges. Unity project for Oculus Quest (android)

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, lighting

I'm making a VR experience in Unity (`version 2019.1.12f`), for the `Oculus` Quest (android build). Some of my objects have white lines in their edges (see below), and I want to know how to get rid of them.

Whitelines: https://i.ibb.co/bXsN9J2/whitelines.png

The quality is maxed out and the anti-aliasing is disabled in the image but even with `8x` I was getting the lines. Using baked global lighting, and all the objects are static.  Also see my Quality Settings, Lighting Settings and Directional Light Settings.

Quality: https://i.ibb.co/ySHfgcD/Quality.png

Lighting: https://i.ibb.co/dKBQbpG/Lighthing.png

Directional: https://i.ibb.co/ZfDJPSz/Directional.png

Here's a overview of the Scene and all the lights present:

Scene: https://i.ibb.co/x6YtXTv/Scene.png

One last thing.. I read somewhere this could be related to `Shaders` but as I have no knowledge in that area I would prefer other options.

Thanks in advance!

- Removing the anti-aliasing doesn't solve the problem.
- I'm using ASTC compression on the textures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to go to the **Nvidia panel** and activate **anti-aliasing** and **ambient occlusion**, problem solved!

Comment: I am wondering how this solved the issue. This settings is a PC level right? How does it affect the non-tethered oculus quest app?

Answer (score 0):

You can try turn on **Ambient Occulision** in **Lightmapping settings**.

By the way,I wonder why are you showing gizmos ?

Comment: I was showing the gizmos because I was thinking it could be a problem related with the use of Area Lights and someone could point that out

Comment: what about ambient occulision ? @JoaquimMoreira

Comment: unfortunately the problem still persists

Comment: so Ambient occulision solved your problem am I right ? @JoaquimMoreira